# Does Android support apk files in Zip64 format?

Tags: android, zip, apk

Can a working apk be built using the Zip64 format? Can it be installed/executed on Android, and what kind of things would be necessary in the Android framework to support this?

The latest (7.0 r31) version of Android's apksigner tool [does not support Zip64](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/+/android-7.0.0_r31/tools/signapk/src/com/android/signapk/ApkSignerV2.java#158). You could, however, use other tools (such as jarsigner) to sign an apk.

Gradle [has supported zip64 for a while](https://docs.gradle.org/1.12/release-notes.html#support-for-building-large-zips), but I couldn't find a good example of using this from, say, the Android gradle plugin.

The only example of an apk I found was [a bug report for apktool](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/29129026-java-util-zip-zipexception-invalid-cen-header-bad-signature) - hypothesised to be Zip64 but later deemed an invalid apk file. I tried unzipping the file via Python's zipfile, which returned a BadZipfile exception (instead of LargeZipFile), so I'm guessing it really is corrupt.

I know that Android has other ways of dealing with apk's with large sizes/numbers of files. I am wondering whether I need to support Zip64 in tools that extract apk's, based on how likely it is to find a zip64 apk in the wild.

Answer (score 1):

No. Android Package Manager -- the component which deals with installing APKs -- does not support ZIP64. It uses [`libziparchive`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/master/libziparchive/) which doesn't support ZIP64. `apksigner` is supposed to mimic what the Android Package Manager does. Hence, `apksigner` doesn't support ZIP64 either.