# What is Android APK size limit (not market limit)?

Tags: android, apk, limit

I read a lot of answers about APK limits (like 50MB, later 100MB, expansion packs, etc.), but all of them seems to be talking about limitation of Google Play or other markets.

What is the APK size limit enforced by Android Studio 2.3. I want to develop an application, which will not be available on public markets.

Comment: the you can create as much you want

Comment: APKs are ZIP archives, which [appear to be limited to 4GB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format)#Limits).

Answer (score 6):

The APK limit for files used by stock Android devices is 4GB since the Package Manager uses [libziparchive](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/master/libziparchive/)

See also [Does Android support apk files in Zip64 format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42799750/7807166)