# What is the maximum size of a sideloaded APK?

Tags: android, apk

What is the maximum size of an APK that can be built and installed (sideloaded) on a recent device equipped with, say, 256GB storage?

I'm not talking about Google Play limits, but rather wondering about the potential limitations of the Android OS itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have sideloaded even applications bigger than 1GB with success on Android devices (mainly VR headsets).

According to [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43590010/what-is-android-apk-size-limit-not-market-limit), the limit is 4GB as for the limit of the libziparchive library (APKs are just Zip archives in the end).

Answer (score -1):

100MB is the max for a sideload

Comment: I doubt this. Do you have a source?

Comment: i meant 150 and it is the first thing that pops up when i search Android app size limit 2021. @Sébastien

Comment: Again, source please? Google Search results are a poor primary source. The only thing I found from Googling is the Google Play _download_ limitations, which is 150MB or 100MB for apps created before 2021-08.